# How do I render conditional validations based on child object values using Yup in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yup

I have an array of `excludedNames`. If `userId.name` is included in the array, `state` should be an optional field, else it is required. How do I build yup validation for this given that I am trying to use .notation to reference the name?

```
const excludedNames = ['karen', 'mike']

export const Schema = object({
    userDetails: array().of(
        object({
            userId: object({
                _id: string().required(),
                name: string().required()
            }),
            locationHistory: array().of(
                object({
                    city: string().required('city cannot be empty'),
                    state: string().when('userId.name' as const, {
                        is: (name: string) => !excludedNames.includes(name),
                        then: string().required('state cannot be empty'),
                        otherwise: string().notRequired(),
                    }),
                   ...other values
                })
            )
        })
    )
});
```